# ASP.NET : Add a value-less attribute to a UserControl

Tags: asp.net, attributes

In ASP.NET, you can add custom HTML tag attributes to a UserControl via

```
myLabel.Attributes['my-custom-attribute'] = "someValue";
// or Attributes.Add()
```

... but **how can I add an attribute that doesn't have a value**? For example, (and I'm not saying that this is what I need) the W3C specification only needs the `checked` attribute present in a checkbox to consider it checked (instead of `checked='true'` or something).

```
<span ID="ctl-blah-blah-myLabel" my-custom-attribute>some text</span>
```

I'm looking into using something like this to tag specific elements on my page for some client-side behavior. I know that I can do the same with classes, but (1) classes are iffy to manipulate server-side, and (2) I kind of don't want to pollute my class declarations just for tagging (that may be weird for some, I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, doing what you're asking is not a well-formed document.  The W3C specification you are looking at is old, as far as the `checked` attribute is concerned.  Proper form, now-a-days, is to put checked="checked".

While many browsers might accept this, I wouldn't recommend that you do it.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?  Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: HTML is not a derivative of XML.  HTML existed long before XML did.  They are both derivatives of SGML.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Origins

Comment: Well, like I said, I had this *bright idea* of tagging HTML elements so that they behave different in client-side code (like tagging them "readonly" or "modified", etc). I know I can do the same with classes, but was just wondering if you can do this as value-less attributes. Good point on the XML spec though. :D +1

Comment: @Richard Why not just use something like: `my-custom-attribute="true"`?  You could accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @smartcaveman Pardon my misspeak, my point was that an HTML document should still be a well formed XML document.  But I removed the offending comment.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla, that still isn't correct.  XHTML should be a well-formed XML document.  It all depends upon the document type.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla ~ or probably even just `my-custom-attribute=""` even, actually. :D

Comment: @smartcaveman It's not a requirement, I know HTML parsers are incredibly tolerant, but I think most would agree that it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the approach you want to take.  It results in malformed XHTML and malformed ASP.NET.  Even the current W3C Specification suggests that what used to be `checked` is now written as `checked="checked"` There are two approaches that make sense.

1. Use an attribute with a boolean value, such as `my-custom-attribute="true"`
2. Use classes.  You said you don't want to pollute your classes, but there is probably a way to structure your class definitions that this won't be a problem.  For starters, you could put markers like this in a separate .css file and make sure you are using appropriate, expressive naming conventions.  Done correctly, the overlap between css behavior and display can be seamless.

Comment: I was thinking more from a JS perspective over a CSS one, but these are some points very well taken. Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to have multiple boolean fields like this I definitely suggest using CSS classes - they are easier to manipulate client-side (like with jQuery, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Using an asp:Literal instead of asp:Label would allow you to do that.

Comment: Oh, but of course I'm not just talking about `Label`s here :D Sorry, if it came out that way. UserControls / WebControls in general. :D

Comment: Touche--but more generally, there are controls that give you more power over the markup :) Prefer HtmlControls to WebControls, for instance. UserControls are a bit of a different beast. Since they are just a composite of other markup, the "property='value'" construct doesn't directly impact the HTML that gets sent to the browser, and you could say "property='true'", and then render the HTML differently in the control.